# Running Objective C (made through XCode) in Windows

Tags: objective-c, xcode, windows, macos, libraries

I'm thinking about learning some Objective C on a Mac (my IDE will be xcode). I was wondering if xcode uses any Mac only libraries, because I want to be able to publish stuff I make in windows?

Short version: can I use projects written in objective c on xcode in windows?

Comment: This isn't really possible, but the closest thing would be http://www.gnustep.org/

Comment: Windows??? Do you really mean that or a PC? If you mean a PC and without having a mac, still you can learn. VMWare, Hackintosh etc can can be used to run MacOSX on you windows PC.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I want to run applications made in xcode in a windows environment (written in objective c). I know windows can run objective c, what I'm wondering is whether or not xcode uses mac-only libraries, and therefore whether or not I can export finished projects made using xcode to windows.

Comment: OK... I got your question, And I don't feel to answer and there are good answers already provided by peers. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No.

There are tools and libraries you can use that will let you run Obj-C on Windows. Cocoa is Apple's library collection and doesn't run on Windows, but GNUStep and Cocotron are alternatives you can use. They don't have all the features of Cocoa.

Comment: GNUStep is based from OPENSTEP, and is more like a fork than a compatible framework (although maybe _Cocoa_ is the fork from the history point of view). Cocotron, on the other hand, is built with the aim to be compatible with Cocoa, and is more suitable for the asker's purpose IMHO.

Comment: @uranusjr I haven't tried cocotron, only gnustep and cocoa, but my impression is that cocotron is unfinished and immature. How mature is cocotron, and how does its currently implemented feature set compare to gnustep?

Comment: ok thnx for the quick replies guys. i'll leave the same comment on ace legend's post: can i use either the GNUStep or the Cocotron libraries with xcode?

Comment: Cocotron is designed for use with XCode. GNUStep is not.

Answer (score -1):

Well. Objective-C is essentially an Apple-only programming language. Therefore, most Objective-C programs can only be executed on OS X and iOS. That said, there are ways to port Objective-C apps to Windows, but it is most likely not worth your time. You can see cocotron, if you want to port. Now, you could program on Windows, but you will still need to execute your app on OS X.

In summary though, you probably should not use Objective-C and Xcode to make Windows Applications. If you don't want to do the work of re-coding, I would suggest using Java, as it is a cross-platform language. Good luck.

Comment: Objective-C works just fine on linux with GNUStep. It's just not used much. GCC supports relatively modern versions of Objective-C.

Comment: Wait. What was with the downvote. First of all, I never said one way or another that is was not possible. In fact, I stated it is possible, just not worth the time. Linux is a lot easier to create apps on, using GNUStep.  I am just saying Objective-C and Xcode, in combination, is usually only used for Cocoa-based apps. I never said it wasn't possible. I just stated that the OP should probably not use it. Running Objective C on Windows requires many open source libraries to port the application.

Comment: My answer says pretty much the same as yours!

Comment: I downvoted because your answer contained false information, which I pointed out in my previous comment. I see you have edited that part now.

Comment: Yeah. I realize that now. I changed it to most Objective-C programs. Actually, really I should have said Cocoa apps. If you don't mind removing the downvote, that would be great, as my answer is actually useful. (Which is the only reason one should downvote.)

Comment: Bummer. Oh, well. Hopefully a few people upvote. 4 rep isn't a huge deal anyway.

Comment: ok thnx for the quick replies guys. but can i use either the GNUStep or the Cocotron libraries with xcode?

Comment: @AceLegend: I can see 0/-2 is your vote. And worst part of SO is that if someone downvotes(-1vote) and he wants to cancel(0vote), he can't, his upvote will make(+1). :@ And trust me I dint downvote you.

Comment: @user1885956, I know that with Cocotron it is meant to be used with Xcode. I actually tried it, but it was very difficult to set up. I never actually finished, but maybe you'll have better luck. http://www.cocotron.org/